# Запись int  в структуру и ошибка сегментации

Tags: c

Приспичило написать программу учета финансов, код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100000 //Максимальная длина списка

struct table {
int day;
int month;
int year;
int summ;
char comment[161];
} consum[MAX], income[MAX];//Массивы структур расходов и доходов

// Добавление адреса в список доходов
void enter_income(void)
{
  int slot;

  slot = find_free_income();

  if(slot==-1) {
    printf("\nСписок заполнен");
    return;
  }

  printf("День: ");
  gets(income[slot].day);

  printf("Месяц: ");
  gets(income[slot].month);

  printf("Год: ");
  gets(income[slot].year);

  printf("Сумма: ");
  gets(income[slot].summ);

  printf("Комментарий: ");
  gets(income[slot].comment);
}
```

Данный код компилируется, программа запускается, но при попытке записать(к примеру) в income.day ошибка сегментации. Если изменить структуру так:

```
struct table {
  char day[3];
  char month[3];
  char year[3];
  char summ[10];
  char comment[161];
} consum[MAX], income[MAX];
```

то все ок, но налаживаемые ограничения, думаю, понятны.

Хочу int. Компилятор GCC, ОС: 64-битный Генту.
Еще компилятор предупреждает для каждой строки с функцией gets() :
 *предупреждение: результат ‘gets’, декларированной с атрибутом warn_unused_result, игнорируется*

/////

Изменил код так:
    struct table {
      int day;
      int month;
      int year;
      long int summ;
      char comment[161];
    } consum[MAX], income[MAX];//Массивы структур расходов и доходов
    // Добавление адреса в список доходов
    void enter_income(void)
    {
      int slot;

```
  slot = find_free_income();

  if(slot==-1) {
    printf("\nСписок заполнен");
    return;
  }

  printf("День: ");
  scanf("%i", income[slot].day);

  printf("Месяц: ");
  scanf("%i", income[slot].month);

  printf("Год: ");
  scanf("%i", income[slot].year);

  printf("Сумма: ");
  scanf("%i", income[slot].summ);

  printf("Комментарий: ");
  scanf("%i", income[slot].comment);
}
```

Вылетает с ошибкой сегментирования:

```
Введите номер нужного пункта: 1
День: 23
Ошибка сегментирования
```

Comment: предлагаю вырезать ненужный код из сообщения, и оставить только описание структур и функции где происходит сегфолт.

Comment: okay

Comment: Еще раз - замените gets на scanf с правильной строкой форматирования.

Comment: scanf("%i", \&income[slot].comment);
_Амперсанд нужен_

Comment: Тошна, пасиба, паминял!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала сделайте или packed structure, или разберитесь с align.

Кстати, еще одно простое решение: читать-писать каждый элемент структуры отдельно.

> gets(income[slot].day);

Не понял. А с каких пор gets получает значение int с клавы? Вы уж определитесь, что Вам нужно. Или строчка как строчка, или число. Но тогда или другая ф-ция для ввода, или надо разбирать самому полученную с stdin строку.

PS: ч0рт, на C++ прога выглядела бы существенно короче, хотя я его не люблю

Comment: Кхм, простите, я совсем-совсем мало знаю о программировании, тем более на C, хоть я и догадываюсь что такое packed structure(вот так? #pragma pack(push, 1) struct { /* ... */ }; #pragma pack(pop) да?) и align(выравнивание? чего? как? куда? зачем?), но как "читать каждый элемент структуры отдельно" не знаю >_<
Поясните ламеру позязя, можно с примерами.

Comment: Оу, пасиба, я подумаю над этим, [юмор]утром... часа через 2 :D[/юмор]

Comment: <pre>
> >_ < Поясните ламеру позязя, можно с примерами.
> Hackeridze
/0
</pre>

Comment: > > >_ < Поясните ламеру позязя, можно с примерами. > Hackeridze /0 

Ну не силен я в этом

Лучше б помог)

Comment: Грабли #1.<p>
<pre>gets(consum[slot].day);</pre><p>
Вместо этого нужно писать <pre>scanf("%i", &consum[slot].day);</pre>
<p>Грабли #2<p>
Положим, структуру, читаем из файла в текстовом виде. Каждая новая строчка - новая запись.
<pre>fscanf(file, "%i%i%i%i%s", &consum[slot].day, &consum[slot].month, &consum[slot].year, &consum[slot].summ, &consum[slot].comment);</pre>
Как-то так. В стандартной библиотеке куча ф-ция для чтения-записи.